# Which hat is the most armored?

Tags: unturned

Clothing. Survival. Official Maps.

Which hats have the more damage reduction? Which ones are useful only for salvaging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the Official Wiki](https://unturned.fandom.com/wiki/Template:Navbox/Clothing_3#Hat), there are 24 hats to be found on Survival Offical Maps:

**15% Damage Reduction:**

- Coalition Helmet
- Fighter Pilot Helmet
- Military Helmet
- Pickelhaube
- Spec Ops Helmet

**10% Damage Reduction**

- Construction Helmet
- Engineer Hat
- Firefighter Helmet

**5% Damage Reduction:**

- Beret
- Cap
- Coalition Beret
- Coalition Cap
- Chef Hat
- Fedora
- Fishing Hat
- Ghillie Hood
- Mafia Fedora
- Police Cap
- Pilot Cap
- RCMP Hat
- Spec Ops Beret
- Tophat
- Toque

**0% Damage Reduction:**

- Farmer Hat